# How to secure Ruby on Rail CRUD actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just got done through the RoR getting started guide and created the blog sample app.

And read the last section on securing CRUD actions via http basic auth: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#security

How else would one secure their CRUD actions/what are some more secure alternatives to the HTTP basic auth shown in the guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout the ruby toolbox for some options on authentication: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

Devise is the most popular library: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this starter application from the [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.io/) project:

- [Rails Authorization with Devise and Pundit](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit/)

Devise provides authentication and user management. Pundit provides authorization and the example app shows how to add access control for each controller method based on roles.